# "Cannot find symbol" when making graphics

Tags: java

I am writing a code to make an insignia for a computer assignment, and the error keeps coming up saying that it "cannot find symbol".  I have read up on multiple site about the format of making lines setting colors, and they all show the exact same format.  I have made an applet before using the same methods and didn't have this problem.  I received and update from java not to long ago and I am not sure if the format has changed.  Here is my simple code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Insignia extends JApplet
{
   public void paint(Graphics page)
   {   
       setBackground(new Color(75,0,130));
       page.setColor(new Color(0,204,255));
       page.drawLine(320, 120, 240, 180);
       page.drawLine(320, 120, 400, 180);
       page.drawLine(400, 180, 400, 300);
       page.drawLine(400, 300, 320, 360);
       page.drawLine(320, 360, 240, 300);
       page.drawLine(240, 300, 240, 180);
   }
}
```

When I go to compile the error pops up for every line from setting color to the last

```
drawLine.ex:   error cannot find symbol
               page.drawLine(240, 300, 240, 180);                        
-------------------^
```

It points right at the period.  I use command prompt to compile and run my programs.  The format looks correct, I've tried different things from document name changes to changing the word before .drawLine.

Comment: Do you have a class called `Graphics` in the same package, by any chance?

Comment: No, that is all I have right now.  I build and test as I go along.  I went back and tested the program that worked before and now I am getting the same error.  I plan on making the graphic more complex, but there is no point in continuing until I fix the error that will ultimately cause me to start all over again.

Comment: Code runs over here...

Comment: As it is, the code you have posted should work. So my guess is that there is a `Graphics`class somewhere who is imported and makes a conflict here. What you should do is add an `@Override` before the method. If it is not the right Graphics, you will have an error because it would not be an override of the JApplet method.

Comment: Thank you, I was sure it would work too.  Maybe it is my version of javac, is there an alternate compiler I can use for java?  I did go by the book I have as well.  Java Software Solutions 7th edition.

Comment: Eclipse have its own compiler, you can try that. Not sure it is a compiler problem, still. What happens if you write the method signature like this `public void paint(java.awt.Graphics page)` ?

Comment: Thank you Cyrille Karmann for your help.  I took a look into the folder that I had my programs in.  It seems that when I was compiling some of my other programs where interfering somehow.  I guess if want to code any sort of program ought to do it in a empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

I guess u miss the `java.awt.Graphics` import.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Insignia extends JApplet {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics page) {
        setBackground(new Color(75, 0, 130));
        page.setColor(new Color(0, 204, 255));
        page.drawLine(320, 120, 240, 180);
        page.drawLine(320, 120, 400, 180);
        page.drawLine(400, 180, 400, 300);
        page.drawLine(400, 300, 320, 360);
        page.drawLine(320, 360, 240, 300);
        page.drawLine(240, 300, 240, 180);
    }
}
```